# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str API, Json in Python

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I am trying to get data from API but facing an error. I need block height from this API.

```
import requests
import json


fetch_json_net = requests.get('https://api.minaexplorer.com/blocks?limit=1')
blk_height_net = fetch_json_net.json()["blocks"]["blockHeight"]
print(blk_height_net)
```

Comment: You want `fetch_json_net.json()["blocks"][0]["blockHeight"]`

Comment: If you set a break point of `print(fetch_json_net.json())` inbetween those two lines, what do you get? I'm guessing that `fetch_json_net.json()["blocks"]` might be a list that you might want the first item of or to iterate over.

Comment: putting 0 in between solves my problem but can you please explain how and why?
@not_speshal

Comment: Because `blk_height_net["blocks"]` is a `list` and not a `dict`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I checked what `fetch_json_net.json()` returns:

```
{'blocks': [{'blockHeight': 115919, 'canonical': True, ...
```

It means `blk_height_net["blocks"]` has a *list* value, not a *dictionary* value.

Therefore, you can get the `blockHeight` value, as follows:

```py
import requests
import json

fetch_json_net = requests.get('https://api.minaexplorer.com/blocks?limit=1')
blk_height_net = fetch_json_net.json()["blocks"][0]["blockHeight"]
print(blk_height_net)
# 115919
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the JSON data. You're attempting to get listed in a dictionary. It will not work if you attempt the slicing approach to get data from list.
To obtain data from a dictionary, use the get method with key.
Here's the code for obtaining data for "blockHeight" for the first Element.

**Method One:**

```
import requests
import json

fetch_json_net = requests.get('https://api.minaexplorer.com/blocks?limit=1')
blk_height_net = fetch_json_net.json()["blocks"][0]["blockHeight"]
print(blk_height_net)
115919
```

**Another Method:**

```
import requests
import json


fetch_json_net = requests.get('https://api.minaexplorer.com/blocks?limit=1')
blk_height_net = fetch_json_net.json().get("blocks")[0].get('blockHeight')
print(blk_height_net)
115919
```